# Using XGBoost in R for regression based model

Tags: r, regression, decision-tree, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to use `XGBoost` as a replacement for `gbm`.

The scores I'm getting are rather odd, so I'm thinking maybe I'm doing something wrong in my code.

My data contains several factor variables, all other numeric.

Response variable is a continuous variable indicating a House-Price.

I Understand that in order to use `XGBoost`, I need to use **One Hot Enconding** for those. I'm doing so by using the following code:

```
Xtest <- test.data
Xtrain <- train.data
XSalePrice <- Xtrain$SalePrice
Xtrain$SalePrice <- NULL

# Combine data  
Xall <- data.frame(rbind(Xtrain, Xtest))

# Get categorical features names
ohe_vars <- names(Xall)[which(sapply(Xall, is.factor))]

# Convert them
dummies <- dummyVars(~., data = Xall)
Xall_ohe <- as.data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = Xall))

# Replace factor variables in data with OHE
Xall <- cbind(Xall[, -c(which(colnames(Xall) %in% ohe_vars))], Xall_ohe)
```

After that, I'm splitting the data back to the test & train set:

```
Xtrain <- Xall[1:nrow(train.data), ]
Xtest <- Xall[-(1:nrow(train.data)), ]
```

And then building a model, and printing the RMSE & Rsquared:

```
# Model
xgb.fit <- xgboost(data = data.matrix(Xtrain), label = XSalePrice,
  booster = "gbtree", objective = "reg:linear",
  colsample_bytree = 0.2, gamma = 0.0,
  learning_rate = 0.05, max_depth = 6,
  min_child_weight = 1.5, n_estimators = 7300,
  reg_alpha = 0.9, reg_lambda = 0.5,
  subsample = 0.2, seed = 42,
  silent = 1, nrounds = 25)

xgb.pred <- predict(xgb.fit, data.matrix(Xtrain))
postResample(xgb.pred, XSalePrice)
```

Problem is I'm getting very off RMSE & Rsxquare:

```
        RMSE     Rsquared 
1.877639e+05 5.308910e-01
```

That are VERY far from the results I get when using GBM.

I'm thinking i'm doing something wrong, my best guess it probably with the One Hot Encoding phase which I'm unfamiliar, So used a googled code with adjustments to my data.

Can someone indicate what am I doing wrong and how to 'fix' it?

**UPDATE:**

After reviewing @Codutie answer, my code has some errors:

```
Xtrain <- sparse.model.matrix(SalePrice ~. , data = train.data)
XDtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = Xtrain, label = "SalePrice")
```

`xgb.DMatrix` produces:

```
Error in setinfo.xgb.DMatrix(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) : 
  The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data
```

`train.data` is data frame, and it has 1453 rows. Label `SalePrice` also contains 1453 values (No missing values)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
train <- dat[train_ind,]
train.y <- train[,ncol(train_ind)]
xgboost(data =data.matrix(train[,-1]), 
   label = train.y, 
   objective = "reg:linear", 
   eval_metric = "rmse",
   max.depth =15, 
   eta = 0.1, 
   nround = 15, 
   subsample = 0.5, 
   colsample_bytree = 0.5, 
   num_class = 12,
   nthread = 3
)
```

Two clues to control XGB for Regression,

1) eta : if eta is small, models tends to overfit

2) eval_metric : Not sure if xgb allowed user to use their own eval_metric. But this metric is not useful when the quantitative dependent variable contains outlier. Check if XGB support hubber loss function.